# SQLite increase won't work

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to increase the value of a column named 'tries', with the following:

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TABLE_NAME + " SET "
                + DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TRIES + " = " + DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TRIES + " +1 WHERE "
                + DataProviderContract.STORAGE.HASHNAME + " = '" +hashName+"'");
```

And here's the Cursor Dump before and after the modification:

```
07-27 22:58:05.579 11573-11838/com.a.s D/ImgManagement: STORAGE DUMP BEFORE: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@75c4874
                                                                             0 {
                                                                                hashname=24969a3f1710cd838c6c1eecd10d31b9b5188a3a4209fb8b2e337a0a26b4dc27
                                                                                type=0
                                                                                date=1469671085
                                                                                tries=0
                                                                             }
                                                                             <<<<<

    07-27 22:58:05.589 11573-11838/com.a.s D/ImgManagement: STORAGE DUMP AFTER: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@75c4874
                                                                             0 {
                                                                                hashname=24969a3f1710cd838c6c1eecd10d31b9b5188a3a4209fb8b2e337a0a26b4dc27
                                                                                type=0
                                                                                date=1469671085
                                                                                tries=0
                                                                             }
```

as you see, there's no difference. I even logged the string that's passing to `db.execSql` and here is it:

```
    07-27 22:58:05.587 11573-11838/com.a.s D/ImgManagement: UPDATE storage SET tries = tries +1 WHERE hashname = '24969a3f1710cd838c6c1eecd10d31b9b5188a3a4209fb8b2e337a0a26b4dc27'
```

Somebody knows what's wrong? I've been trying to do it for hours and can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQLiteDatabase.execSQL()` executes a single SQL statement that is *NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data*.

`SQLiteDatabase.update()` is just a convenience method for updating rows in the database that take values in `ContentValues` that internally uses a SQLiteStatement to do its job.

Binding arguments avoid the need to quote or escape values.

Then, you should use:

```
final SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("UPDATE " +       
    DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TABLE_NAME + " SET " +
    DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TRIES + " = " +  
    DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TRIES + " +1 WHERE " +
    DataProviderContract.STORAGE.HASHNAME + " = ?");
stmt.bindString(1, hashName);
final int rows = stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
```

Comment: Hmmm, I replaced my code by this and the dump was exactly the same, the row isn't changing. Hashname has an UNIQUE contraint, is this a problem? Also, why my code is wrong?

Comment: In this case `rows` should contain the number of rows changed.

Comment: that's the strange part, it says 1

Comment: the creation of TRIES is like this: DataProviderContract.STORAGE.TRIES + " integer default 0,"

Comment: sorry, my fault, problem with my dump function